Verilator: How to create a library ( a .a or .so file) from multiple .sv files?
I've got several .sv files that need to be put into a single library (probably a .so or .a file), for example a directory that has the following .sv files:

control.sv  hotstate.sv  microcode.sv  next_address.sv  stack.sv
switch.sv  test_gen.sv  timer.sv  variable.sv

The hotstate.sv file is the toplevel file here as it instantiates modules from all the others.
I tried to compile with the following verilator command line:

$ verilator --protect-lib hotstate -Wno-fatal --cc -Mdir
obj_dir_hotstate/ control.sv microcode.sv next_address.sv stack.sv
timer.sv variable.sv switch.sv hotstate.sv

However, the files that are created in obj_dir_hotstate don't seem to include anything but output for control.sv, here's the file listing:

hotstate.cpp hotstate.sv Vcontrol_classes.mk Vcontrol.cpp  Vcontrol.h
Vcontrol__idmap.xml Vcontrol.mk Vcontrol__pch.h
Vcontrol_PScpt0__DepSet_h0d9d8c4c__0.cpp
Vcontrol_PScpt0__DepSet_h0d9d8c4c__0__Slow.cpp
Vcontrol_PScpt0__DepSet_h7c3873b2__0.cpp
Vcontrol_PScpt0__DepSet_h7c3873b2__0__Slow.cpp Vcontrol_PScpt0.h
Vcontrol_PScpt0__Slow.cpp Vcontrol_PSvGIS.cpp Vcontrol_PSvGIS.h
Vcontrol__ver.d Vcontrol__verFiles.dat

Do I need to run verilator separately for each .sv file in the directory to generate a .a file for each of them and then someone (not quite sure how at this point) all those .a files get gathered into a single libhotstate.so ? (seems cumbersome)
I'm trying to use the veriltor example from verilator/examples/make_protect_lib as an example for doing this, but that example only contains one toplevel file (top.v) and one file that serves to create a libverilated_secret.a file.

So apparently you only list the .sv file with the toplevel module of your design on the verilator command line. The rest of the dependent .sv files appear to be pulled in automatically:

verilator --protect-lib hotstate -Wno-fatal --cc -Mdir obj_dir_hotstate/ hotstate.sv

Next you go into obj_dir_hotstate and run the makefile:

cd obj_dir_hotstate ; make -f Vhotstate.mk

And you'll see that it's created libhotstate.a, libhotstate.so and hotstate.o files.
So it's not like gcc where you need to actually create object files for each source file and then link them into a shared library.
